# Efficient way to broadcast from sockjs-node?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, sockjs

I'd like to broadcast messages to all clients connected to my sockjs-node server.

Right now I have the following code

```
var clients = {};
var echo = sockjs.createServer();
echo.on('connection', function(conn) {
    clients[conn.id] = conn;

    for(key in clients) {
        if(clients.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            clients[key].write('test');
        }
    }

    conn.on('close', function() {
        delete clients[conn.id];
    });
});
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it ?

Maybe

```
var clients = [];
var echo = sockjs.createServer();
echo.on('connection', function(conn) {
    var index = clients.push(conn);

    var lenght = clients.length;
    while(length--) {
        if(clients[length] !== undefined) {
            clients[length].write('test');
        }
    }

    conn.on('close', function() {
        delete clients[index];
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Over-optimization. I doubt you'll ever see the difference.

Comment: I'm trying to be fast and low on memory on my shared server.

Comment: Lets start with the basic question: are you actually having issues with speed/memory usage? Or are you pre-optimizing (which is the root of all evil)? Whatever it is this kind of optimizations won't give you any noticeable boost to performance.

Comment: Referencing to the conn object instead of cloning it might be a good idea. I have no idea how.

Comment: I would suggest using http://socket.io/ that has built in support for broadcasting. If you want, I could post an example

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I switched to sockjs because socket.io was using too much memory.

Comment: You better avoid `while` loops.

Answer (score 0):

1.)for...in is slower then regular for or while, not by much
2.)also probably getting a value from an object is slower then getting a value from an array (cause you need to get address from a string, but you can calculate address from an array index imminently), also not by much
So second one is faster.